# need to exclude the few values while using if condition

Tags: shell, sh

I have two files having the values where i need to ignore **mov_order** and process the account in few cases. Can someone help me to fix the issue

```
file1: 
input_file='/efs/home/ps604312/testing_vela/entity_list.txt'
```

```
staging staging-modules mov_order
staging staging-modules account
```

```
file2:
OTHER_ENTITY_LIST='/efs/home/ps604312/testing_vela/other_entity_list.txt'
```

```
if [[ "${ENTITY_NAME}" != "${OTHER_ENTITY_NAME}"  &&  "${PRODUCT_ENTITY}" == "staging" ]];

then
        echo "syncing only "${ENTITY_NAME}" entity"
        echo "folder "${ENTITY_NAME}" is exist"

        rsync -avzh ${SOURCE_PATH}/"${ENTITY_NAME}" ${DESTINATION_PATH}/"${ENTITY_NAME}"

else

           rsync -avzh ${SOURCE_PATH}/"${ENTITY_NAME}" ${DESTINATION_PATH}/"${ENTITY_NAME}"

      fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is using multiple conditions in single if statement. The following snippet gives an easy illustration for the same

```bash
## function with multiple if conditions with && operator

firstArg=true
secondArg=false
thirdArg=true
fourthArg=true


function test {
    if [ $firstArg == "true" ] && [ $secondArg == "true" ]; then
        echo "first and second are true"
    elif [ $thirdArg == "true" ] && [ $fourthArg == "true" ]; then
        echo "third and fouth are true"
    else
        echo "None was true"
    fi
}


test
```

- Run

```bash
╰─ bash test.sh
third and fouth are true
```